# add space between list elements at odd position

Tags: java

I have a string:

`str = "Hello there"`

I am removing the whitespace:

`String[] parts = str.split("\\s+");`

Creating a List and populating it with the parts:

```
List<String> theParts = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        theParts.add(parts[i]);
      }
```

The size of the List is 2.Now, I want to increase it's size in order to be the same size as another list.

Let's say the other list has size 3.
So, I check:

```
if (otherList.size() > theParts.size()) {
```

and then, I want to change the `theParts` list in order to contain an empty space (the number which shows how much greater the otherList is) between it's parts.

So, I want `theParts` to be (add a space at every odd position):

```
theParts[0] = "Hello"
theParts[1] = " "
theParts[2] = "there"
```

I am not sure if this can be happen with Lists, but I can't think another solution.

Or use something like join (doesn't work, just an idea to use something like this):

```
if (otherList.size() > theParts.size()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < otherList.size(); i++) {
      if (i%2 !=0) {
        String.join(" ", theParts);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why can't you just add a `String` only containing a space after you add each member of `parts` ? `theParts.add(parts[i]); theParts.add(" ");`

Comment: So you basically add back the whitespace you take?

Comment: Why are you attempting to insert the space in the middle of the List and not just push another element to the end? Or since you already know the length of the other list why don't you create a list of that size and insert items from the split string into that list alternatively with the empty space?

Comment: What happens when the other list has more than twice the size of theParts? Should I pad the end with more spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert the spaces as you're populating the list:

```
List<String> theParts = new ArrayList<>(2 * parts.length - 1);
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0) theParts.add(" ");
  theParts.add(parts[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks!(upv).I can use also `List<String> theParts = new ArrayList<>(otherList.size());`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `word break` regex:

```
public void test() throws Exception {
    String str = "Hello there";
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\b"));
    for ( String s : strings ) {
        System.out.println("'"+s+"'");
    }
}
```

this will retain all of the spaces for you.

> 'Hello'
>
> ' '
>
> 'there'

Answer (score -2):

```
for(String dis : theParts){
          newParts.add(dis);//'newPart is another list '
          String last = parts[parts.length -2];  // until new list read last element
          if(!last.equals(dis)){ 
              newParts.add(" "); 
          }if(last.equals(dis)){
              newParts.add(" "); 
          }
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Okay... i will next time

Comment: You can [edit] immediately - no need to wait until "next time".